# Does constructor returns null?

Tags: c#

I'm writing C# program, and VisualStudio's VSTO wizard generates below code.

```cs
private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
            {
                if (resourceReader != null)
                {
                    return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I think  `if (resourceReader != null)` is redundant, because constructor always returns not null. Isn't it?

Comment: That's correct, `resourceReader` could never be null in this instance - it will either throw an exception, or return a `StreamReader`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In regular sane code, a constructor will not return `null`. There *are* some convoluted ways you can *force* a constructor to return `null`, but it is such a bizarre edge case that you will never see it. To all intents and purposes: `new` on this object will never return `null` - and it is completely pointless to add a null-check after a `new()`, especially for something sensible like `StreamReader`.

A *simple* case where you can get null:

```
object obj = new int?()
```

But this is simply exposing the subtle boxing behavior of nullable types. The more *complicated* way of getting a contructor to return `null` requires evil:

```
static void Main() {
    var obj = new MyFunnyType(); // wow! null!
}

class MyFunnyProxyAttribute : ProxyAttribute {
    public override MarshalByRefObject CreateInstance(Type serverType) {
        return null;
    }
}
[MyFunnyProxy]
class MyFunnyType : ContextBoundObject { }
```

Comment: You missed a directive: `using System.Evil;`

Answer (score 1):

According to ReSharper:

```
if (resourceReader != null)
```

> Expression is always true

That's because the `StreamReader` constructor will **never** return `null`. In fact, I can't think of any time off my head where a constructor would *ever* return `null`.

Comment: I'm not sure I would rely on R#, its heuristics are sometimes wrong.

Comment: @svick 99/100 they are usually spot on.

Comment: Actually, it can be done - even for classes; I'll edit it into my example, but it is purely for curiosity

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah I thought there has to be some kind of way, that's why I said I couldn't think of a time. Nice work for finding one :)

Answer (score 0):

`Readline` or other methods can return null but `streamreader` won't. Because you are assigning the instance in the same time you create it. So it is useless to check.

Answer (score 0):

constructor return their class reference. and it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors Should Not Return Null Values To Everywhere and On EveryTime